# how to control other scripts by a main script and pass to them parameters when they are running

Tags: php, command-line, stdin, proc-open

I have a **main.php** and **test.php**.

1. **test.php** should be executed by **main.php**
2. both scripts must be run infinite.
3. **main.php** must checks in periods of time that **test.php** is running or not and if it isnt running (in case of occuring errors) execute it again.
4. I must have error logs too.
5. if **main.php** recieve `'test stop'` it sends `'close'` to **test.php** and **test.php** must stop (I dont know how send my orders (such as `'test stop'`) to **main.php** after that executed?)

I have this samples:

**main.php**:

```
     <?php

function execute(){
    $desc = array(
        0 => array('pipe', 'r'), 
        1 => array('pipe', 'w'),
        2 => array('file', 'log.txt', 'a') 
    );
    $cmd = "start /b C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe test.php";
    $p = proc_open($cmd, $desc, $pipes);
    $res[0] = $p;
    $res[1] = $pipes;
    return $res;
}
$res = execute();

while(1) {

    $status = proc_get_status($res[0]);
    if (!$status['running']) {
        $res = execute();
    }

    if ( trim(fgets(STDIN)) == 'stop test' ) {
      fwrite($res[1][0], 'close');

      fclose($res[1][0]);
      fclose($res[1][1]);
      fclose($res[1][2]);
      proc_close($res[0]);
      break;
    }

}
?>
```

**test.php**:

```
<?php

while (1) {

     // ---------
     // other commands
     // ---------
     // ---------


$status = trim(fgets(STDIN));

if ($status == 'close') exit();

}
?>
```

ok this was summary of my codes but they dont work right.

for example when script arrive to this line `$status = trim(fgets(STDIN));` in **test.php** it waits until an input and if we dont send any input for it, script stops and dont run rest of code but I want script runs in the loop and executes orders until **main.php** pass an input to him.

I'm working on windows.

Comment: why no one answer me even a simple answer??!! :((

Comment: If your solution is for linux, its not problem. say here. meybe I could convert it in windows syntax. please help me :))

Comment: Tomorrow I start a `bounty`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that PHP isn't the best tool for what you're trying to accomplish. Why don't you write a program in C or Visual Basic or something?

But it's solvable in PHP too:
I'd suggest to create your own error-handling function and assign it in test.php via the **set_error_handler('my_custom_error_function')** function.

In my_custom_error_function() you can log the error and restart test.php
Appending a line to a logfile can be done via  **file_put_contents('.\error.log', $error_string, FILE_APPEND)**

fgets() expects an open file handle. So you may want to check your routines (or provide more code).  You may want to look into file_get_contents() too.